# How to get web content using bash

Tags: bash

Hello there I want to get the response of my php file. I already tried `wget -q -O - https://juanvpn.co/api/login?username=kuyajaaam&password=example` its response is 0 but when I try it in browser its response is 1

Comment: You must quote the URL, because it contains characters that have special meaning to the shell: `wget -q -O - "https://juanvpn.co/api/login?username=kuyajaaam&password=example"`

Comment: Thanks man. That answer solved my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must quote the URL because it contains characters that have special meaning to the shell. If you put your URL in quotes the shell will ignore the special characters in the string and it will work fine.

Thanks to [@Janos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/641955/janos) in the comments above

Comment: My bad I just saw this question in the triage. I edited it to give credits to the @janos